Task :videosdk.live_react-native-webrtc:packageDebugResources FAILED
I ejected my react native from app from Expo to add some native codes for Android. Ever since I did that, I have been getting an implicit dependency error for videosdk.live_react-native-webrtc.
Here is the error:

I have tried declaring an explicit dependency on :rnwebrtc:generateDebugResValues from :videosdk.live_react-native-webrtc:packageDebugResources using Task#dependsOn.
And I got this error in the image:

On line 29, I wrote this:
tasks.named(':videosdk.live_react-native-webrtc:packageDebugResources')
{
   dependsOn ':rnwebrtc:generateDebugResValues'
}

